# How am I supposed to excel at Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I've had this problem multiple times because of people.
I now have 3 accounts with StackOverflow because my accounts keep getting restricted for "bad questions".

My question is though, how can you restrict a new comer for bad questions when we're still learning how everything is?

I don't know how every person on here thinks, so how am I supposed to know how to perfectly word the question. I try the best I can, and people don't help me by mentioning things I should say so I can edit it to fill their needs. They just down-vote and leave. No comments or anything.

Then I run into the issue with people just flat out being mean. I understand this is an online community, but not everyone is perfect. I don't understand why people won't help the newcomers like me make better posts, not just down-vote and get me restricted from posting.

It's stupid. I like StackOverflow, I do. It's the only place I can go where I can get support for my issues and such. 
But I ask a question about where to find good resources and people respond with, "Go search for it and try different things"

I'm smart enough for that, I searched for a couple hours and couldn't find anything; yet I still get crap for it. I'm trying to understand the twisted logic some people have here, and I can't seem to understand.

I'm new, don't restrict me. Help me.

How can I get better if no one here will help me improve?

Comment: Please don't create extra accounts. It violates our terms of service severely.

Comment: There's tons of links to resources on how to ask questions on SO in the help center, and they're accessible from the ask question page. Did you read those?

Comment: Yes, I do. But we all type out things differently. I can't help that. So something may make sense to me, but not to others. And they just down-vote it instead of asking questions

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Multiple accounts in and of themselves don't, actually. It's more that *usually* when folks create multiple accounts, they do so to commit vote fraud, evade suspensions, etc. That is the kind of behaviour we frown upon, but just having multiple accounts that are used for different purposes or to maintain anonymity is fine.

Comment: @Anna so you say that when someone get a post ban it's OK to create brand new account to keep asking his bad questions? Over and over? Sorry but I don't really agree. If that's the case the post ban is totally useless.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I think you misread Anna's comment.

Comment: @Mat she disagree with Richard who ask the OP to stop creating new accounts to bypass the ban. Simply put, it can be easily interpreted as confirmation of the OP actions.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: no. Richard's comments is incorrect in that creating multiple accounts _in itself_ is not a violation of the TOS. Anna's comment explains that. And states that creating several accounts to evade bans is "frowned upon".

Comment: @Mat OK, after second and third reading of the comments it's clear but most people won't go that far. Anyway guess I overreacted, seeing such cases too many times here.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Am I in trouble? http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/why-are-there-so-many-high-ranked-users-that-have-never-asked-a-question#comment16388_6078 ;P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That's an incredibly optimistic statement if I've seen one.

Answer (score 30):

> How can I get better if no one here will help me improve?

If you have somehow managed to get *two prior* accounts suspended (and yet still have managed to get around the question ban), and yet you still keep [asking questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500080/how-to-create-appdata-folder-with-c-sharp), I'm not sure you can be helped. The close reasons, especially nowadays, are descriptive enough to give you a good idea of what you did wrong.

Let's examine [that question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500080/how-to-create-appdata-folder-with-c-sharp) in detail. I'll go sentence-by-sentence:

> Well, I don't know how to type all this so bear with me please.

This is useless information. It doesn't help us help you in any way. All it does is take up space.

Don't take a conversational tone. Restrict your questions to the facts.

> This is beyond me, I'm still a newb at C#.

See the above, only moreso. Do not *apologize* as part of asking a question. Just ask the question.

> I basically need to create a folder in the roaming application data of the current user running the program. I also need to access another folder in the application data section and then replace a file with a copy of the file in the application data folder I had created.

This is the actual *question* part of your question. However, it is *woefully* inadequate. I'm guessing you're talking about the Windows directory "User/Roaming/AppData", where "User" is replaced by the username.

There are several things wrong with this question. First, I had to *guess* at what you're talking about. That's never good; always be clear and specific.

Second, to answer this question, you need to know two things: how to create directories, and how to find the "User/Roaming/AppData" directory (assuming that there aren't other issues that I don't know anything about. And if there are, you should have encountered them and put them in your question).

Making a directory is something you ought to be able to look up on MSDN. So... why didn't you? Why didn't you ask "how do I find the 'User/Roaming/AppData' directory?" Did you put *any* effort into solving the problem yourself?

The fact that you're "a newb at C#" does not absolve you of the responsibility to do diligence in figuring things out for yourself *before* asking for our help. That's not optional. The tooltip on the downvote arrow says, "This question does not show any research effort;..." And yours does not seem to. It's more likely you thought, "I don't know how to do this, so I'll ask someone."

That doesn't fly here.

---

From your comments:

> And they just down-vote it instead of asking questions

OK, let me make sure that you understand this:

***Stack Overflow is not a forum!***

The way SO works is ***not*** that you ask a poorly-worded question, then we ask you to clarify it, then you add details, then we ask you for more details, then after a few repetitions of this finally the question is reasonable, so someone answers it. That crap may fly on a forum, but *not here*.

You ask a good question the *first* time. It is incumbent upon *you* to ask a good question *first*. That's *your responsibility*: to provide all of the information we need to answer your question. If you can't do that, if you chronically just fire off quicky questions, hoping that people will stop and try to pry information out of you, then we don't need you asking questions here.

We have plenty of people who are willing to take responsibility for asking good questions who need us. We don't need to take the time to convince you to do what you should be doing.

Comment: All fine, but 'crap' is unnecessary.

Comment: I dunno. We use the word crap a lot around here.

Answer (score 10):

**When asking questions:**

- Try to be as clear and concise as possible.

  - This is especially true when posting code.  No one wants to read a ton of code, especially when it's not relevant to the problem at hand
- Make sure you put research/effort into your question.

  - NB: just because you put research in outside of SO and couldn't find an answer does **not** mean it's not on SO.  So, before asking a question, make sure no one else has asked it already.
- If the question that has already been asked has an explanation that you do not understand, cite the question/answer and be explicit about what you do not understand
- Try to avoid asking overly subjective questions and questions that are too broad.

  - Additionally, don't ask questions like "How do I do XYZ?"

**Answering questions:**

- As a user with low-rep, in the beginning it may take a little while to gain some momentum since the community does not know how much faith to put in you.  Regardless, even if you do not have that much experience, there are tons of questions asked by people who virtually know nothing about programming, so as long as you're in the right place at the right time, you can get a decent amount of rep.
- Don't just post links as answers.  It's great to cite references in your answers, but references themselves are not answer--they are comments.

  - On that note, do not leave comments as answers.  Many people do this simply because they do not have the rep required to comment.
- Instead of just providing a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), for example, also give an explanation about how it works.

  - Just giving an answer, unless it's extraordinarily straight-forward, is not good form, IMHO.

**In general:**

- Have good formatting.  No one wants to read something that doesn't look good.
- Make sure to read the [About](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) sections.

  - The [Help Section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, has tons of information on good questions/answers/etc.
  - Additionally, as Cole Johnson pointed out, [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) is also quite informative.
- Make edits to improve your posts, if necessary.
- Finally, SO is **NOT** a forum or a blog, so please don't treat it as such.

  - SO is not a casual conversation site, when asking questions leave irrelevant *commentary* such as:

    - "I'm a complete noob..."
    - "I'm a second year undergrad working on..."
    - "Well, I don't know how to type all this so bear with me please."

In response to your comments:

> My question is though, how can you restrict a new comer for bad
>   questions when we're still learning how everything is?

You've answered the question yourself.  Newcomers don't know how everything works, they're still learning, so restrictions are set in place to not only maintain the quality of the site, but also to help newcomers adjust to SO.

> But I ask a question about where to find good resources and people
>   respond with, "Go search for it and try different things"

*One of the categories for off-topic questions:*

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
>   attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem
>   and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is though, how can you restrict a new comer for bad
>   questions when we're still learning how everything is?

We generally recommend checking out the help center before you ask questions. This will help you to learn how questions are intended to be asked.

In the help center you will also see that it is strongly recommended that you search the site thoroughly before asking. If you do this you will likely be forced to read some questions that are  not closed or heavily down-voted, note how those questions are asked and use them as a model.

In short, learn by reading good posts **before** you write bad posts, and you will not get banned.

> I'm trying to understand the twisted logic some people have here, and
>   I can't seem to understand.

Our logic isn't twisted, at least my logic isn't twisted I can't speak for everyone, SO receives thousands of questions every day, many of which are great questions that deserve great answers, and some of them... well aren't great questions, which often times can't really be answered.

In order to keep the site useful, the ratio of good questions with good answers to bad questions with bad answers must be maintained. The vote system and close system are the primary means of maintaining that ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Over the years, I have found [this piece](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) by Eric Raymond useful to help me understand how one should (ideally) ask questions in the many helpful places on the net (originally mailing lists or news groups, then forums, now Stack Overflow).

Not saying I adhere to each and every piece of advice it contains, but if nothing else, it helps me understand why other people could think I have asked a stupid, sorry: *insufficiently  researched* question.

I am pretty sure you'll find many good answers to your question in that little essay.